Error connecting to my Apache setup on clean install
I installed Apache on a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 22.04) as part of installing Open Project. When attempting to navigate to the page that should have been set up I get the following errors:
Mon Apr 22 00:21:58.277431 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 445844:tid 140379596748352] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:6000 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Mon Apr 22 00:21:58.297601 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 445844:tid 140379596748352] [client 67.168.145.178:57710] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
Here's my .conf file:
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName <domain>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:443/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName <domain>
  DocumentRoot /opt/openproject/public

  ProxyRequests off

  Include /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/vhost/*.conf
  IncludeOptional /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/custom/vhost/*.conf

  # Can't use Location block since it would overshadow all the other proxypass d>
  ProxyPass /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/
</VirtualHost>

I'm super new at this so I'm not sure how to proceed with debugging. Can anyone help point me to what might be going wrong/how I can start to get this working?

The error tells you that port 6000 in your localhost is not up. Be sure it is running, you can use nmap or just curl http://localhost:6000/openproject/ to see if the service is up.

You're right that it does look like that's the issue. Here's the curl error:
Failed to connect to localhost port 6000 after 4 ms: Connection refused
As I try to do the legwork myself, any pointers on how I would get that up and running would be super appreciated :)

What are you using to run openproject?  I think you should look into theopenproject forum for your answer, for example : https://community.openproject.org/topics/4011 . Once you make it run, you may  come back here if things are not working (Apache side). If the openproject forum is not helpful, I recommend you to create a separate question to know why it is not running.
